# Is it possible to use Cloud Storage as your source in a Cloud Build trigger?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-build

I've seen in [these docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit) that show that you can submit a Cloud Build with a Cloud Storage source with the `gcloud builds submit` command. Is there a way that I can create a Cloud Build trigger that has a Cloud Storage bucket as its source as well? I ask because looking through the docs, it looks like Cloud Build triggers can only have Git platforms or inline config as their CloudBuild.yaml sources, and not Cloud Storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the moment, Google Cloud Storage is not yet supported as a repository for Cloud Build triggers. You may only use the following as per Google Cloud Build documentation:

- GitHub
- GitLab
- Bitbucket

You may refer to this documentation on [creating and managing build triggers](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/create-manage-triggers) for more information.

You may also file this as a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) so that Google Cloud engineers could take a look at this. Please be advised that this doesn't have a specific ETA but you can keep track of its progress once the ticket has been created.